# How to parse a multiple node with openxml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, openxml

I am trying to parse a sample XML using SQL. I was able to obtain a result but there are some multiple nodes which does not appear. The sample XML file below was used. You will see two nodes `<Undly>`. In my code, everything appears except for the second `<Undly>`. Thanks

```
<SecDefUpd>
    <Instrmt Status="1">
        <Evnt EventTyp="5" Dt="2005-12-19"/>
        <Pty R="22" ID="XASE">
          <Sub Typ="27" TID="2005-12-17"/>
        </Pty>
        <Pty R="22" ID="XCBO">
          <Sub Typ="27" TID="2005-12-17"/>
        </Pty>
    </Instrmt>
    <Undly STyp="4" ></Undly>
    <Undly STyp ="5"></Undly>
</SecDefUpd>
```

Here is my expected result:

```
Status | EventTyp | Dt         | R  | ID   | Typ | TID        | STyp
-------+----------+------------+----+------+-----+------------+------
   1   |     5    | 2005-12-19 | 22 | XASE | 27  | 2005-12-17 |    4
   1   |     5    | 2005-12-19 | 22 | XASE | 27  | 2005-12-17 |    5
   1   |     5    | 2005-12-19 | 22 | XCBO | 27  | 2005-12-17 |    4
   1   |     5    | 2005-12-19 | 22 | XCBO | 27  | 2005-12-17 |    5
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Try xml type methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi marc_s, sorry for that. I am using Sql Server. Thanks